# How do I use nested schemas in mongoose, using 'type', to create arrays?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, nested, schema

I am trying to create a nested mongoose schema that uses 'type' to create a nested array.

The schema that I think I am having an issue with is "chorePerson".

Here is the data that I am trying to put into a schema:

```
{
  "chart": [
    {
      "ordinal": 0,
      "chorePerson": [
        {
          "person": "emily",
          "chore": "Catbox"
        },
        {
          "person": "Steve",
          "chore": "Dishes"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Here is my current schema.  Note the use of "type" for "chart" and "chorePerson"

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const chorePersonSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    person: {type: String, requried: true},
    chore: {type: String, required: true},
});


const chartSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    ordinal: {type: Number, required: true},
    chorePerson:{ type: chorePersonSchema },
});


// create the schema
const ChoreChartSchema = new Schema({

    affiliation: {type: String, required: true},
    currentWeekNumber: {type: Number, required: true},
    currentYear: {type: Number, required: true},

    chart:{ type: chartSchema },

    date: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
})

module.exports = ChoreChart = mongoose.model('cm_chorechart', ChoreChartSchema)
```

When I run my code this is what I get before the crash:

```
{ _id: 5c742ed116a095522c38ddfc,
  affiliation: 'family',
   currentYear: 2019,
   currentWeekNumber: 9,
   date: 2019-02-25T20:26:33.914Z,
  chart: [ { ordinal: 0, chorePerson: [Array] } ] }
```

I think... chorePerson is causing the error... but I don't know how to fix it.
Here is the exception:

```
(node:6728) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ObjectExpectedError: Tried to set nested object field `chart` to primitive value `[object Object]` and strict mode is set to throw.
```

**What I have tried**

I tried this schema:

```
const chartSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    ordinal: {type: Number, required: true},

    chorePerson : [{
        person : String,
        chore : String
        }]       
});
```

**Update:**

OK... so I went back to basics and this works, but it's not how I want the final schema to be.  Can anybody help out with nesting this ?

```
// create the schema
const ChoreChartSchema = new Schema({

    affiliation: {type: String, required: true},
    currentWeekNumber: {type: Number, required: true},
    currentYear: {type: Number, required: true},

//    chart:{ type: chartSchema },

    chart:[{
            ordinal: 0,
            chorePerson : [{
                person : String,
                chore : String
            }]
    }],

    date: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was easier than I thought:

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    const chorePersonSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        person: {type: String, requried: true},
        personID: {type: String, required: true},
        chore: {type: String, required: true},
        choreID: {type: String, required: true},
    });

    const chartSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        ordinal: {type: Number, required: true},

        chorePerson : [{ type:chorePersonSchema }]       
    });


    // create the schema
    const ChoreChartSchema = new Schema({

        affiliation: {type: String, required: true},
        weekNumber: {type: Number, required: true},
        year: {type: Number, required: true},

        chart:[{type: chartSchema}],

        date: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    })

    module.exports = ChoreChart = mongoose.model('cm_chorechart', ChoreChartSchema)
```

Comment: How can you write chart:[{type: chartSchema} OR {type: someOtherSchema}], I mean chart can be array of chartSchema object or someOtherScheme object..is it possible to do a union type?Thanks